# PayPal 401 Oauth Error

Tags: magento2, paypal

My Magento2 ecommerce website (bizzyizzysboutique.com) is returning a 401 response from PayPal on every page, including the home page (likely from the Minicart sidebar that is included on every page)

https://www.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token

Response
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}

Is this error anything to be concerned with and/or is it expected? The PayPal integration seems to be working properly for the most part (aside from an intermittent issue that a few customers have run into but I am going to post separately about that as I don't think it is related to this error).

Comment: I get exactly the same error since an upgrade from 2.2.8 to 2.3.3 once again it doesn't seem to be affecting PayPal checkout.